# Laravel Cron Scheduling not working after update (5.6)

Tags: php, laravel, cron, lumen

I previously had Laravel's scheduling working on version [5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling) but after updating to [5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling) it seems to have stopped working. The schedule does not run automatically.

I have included my `Kernel.php`, and the line I'm using in cron.
If I run `php artisan schedule:run` manually, the schedule works just fine and the command runs. I therefore assume there's something wrong when editing by `crontab -e`. Or is there something I've missed when updating Laravel (actually Lumen) versions?

I've tried stopping and restarting cron, too.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\CreateReport::class
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('create:report')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

My cron line:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/api && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I use `php /var/www/MYPROJECT/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` in 5.6

Comment: Your first step should be writing to a log file instead of /dev/null so you can see if there are any errors reported.

Comment: @Devon that helped me reach an answer, thanks!